# What is the purpose of bookmarking questions?

Tags: support, faq

It shows no increase in the reputation points of the asker, then what is the purpose of being able to bookmark questions by clicking on bookmark icon with a star?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you bookmark a question you'll receive updates to it (edits, comments, and new answers). One use case is if you're interested in a question and wish to follow it's progress. By "starring" it you've bookmarked it and the system will provide updates to you in the StackExchange SuperCollider™ as if you were the owner of the question and a banner on the site when items change.