# In a comment on question I asked for more info from the asker - will I be notified when he gives that info?

Tags: support, notifications

I was asking for some details from his system - do I need to look at that question regularly myself or am I notified about edits/comments from the asker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not directly notified of any edits to the question, though you will be notified of future comments. To receive notifications about changes to the question I recommend you favorite the question.

- [What is the purpose of favoriting](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2462/what-is-the-purpose-of-favoriting-questions)

Comment: much better solution :-)