# Should I notify about edits in the question comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, asking-questions

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [Using chown successfully but not actually changing user ownership in Ubuntu bash on Windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156814/using-chown-successfully-but-not-actually-changing-user-ownership-in-ubuntu-bash)

A user in the comments gave me some input on how to edit my question further for them to be able to give me some answers. I'm now in the dillema of should I comment back to notify them of the edits or do they already get notified?

According to [this post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5663/in-a-comment-on-question-i-asked-for-more-info-from-the-asker-will-i-be-notifi) I would say commenting back is perfectly okay but it doesn't explicity point out the best proven practice for askers on Stack Exchange forums. I want an explicit answer on whether comments can be used to notify people of edits to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edits do not notify users when done.  The system will only notify you about edits when someone else revises your post(s).

If you want to let the user know that you did your edits, you need to tell them explicitly - there is no automated notification system for other users about a specific post being edited.

And make sure to prefix your comment with @UserName for the user who you want to notify - otherwise they get no notification.

Answer (score 3):

Another point to mention is you should prefix comments with @UserName because they will not know you made a comment to them.

For example on the same thread your comment to me an hour ago:

> Sadly I do not know much about filesystems at all. I'm just starting
>   out with the Linux CLI and learning as I go, about filesystems too
>   apparently :) The linked question was marked as a possible duplicate
>   of mine, hence the clarification in the EDIT section. – Amar Cerim 1
>   hour ago

I did not get a notification. I only stumbled across it through the Q&A here about that question. I only stumbled across this Q&A because it appeared in General Chatroom as a new Meta Q&A advert.

To make a long story short, put @WinEunuuchs2Unix at the start of a comment you wish to make to me. Or as in the case of my last comment to you I put @dessert into the middle. That works too.