# Does favoriting questions help to get an answer?

Tags: discussion, support, unanswered-questions, faq-suggestion

I've read [What if I don’t get a good answer?](https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty) and in meta [What is the purpose of favoriting questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2462/what-is-the-purpose-of-favoriting-questions).

- Does favoriting (clicking the star) highlight my question to others?
- Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 11):

No, favoriting a question does nothing, to my knowledge, to better highlight a question. If you're looking to get your question highlighted the best way to do so is with a [bounty](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties).

You can have your question "bumped" by editing and *adding* more details about the problem, things you've tried, or clarifying items.

Comment: Thanks, but if I don't have enough to set a bounty ?

Comment: Earn more reputation! I've updated my answer with a bit more information,

Comment: Adding more detail bumps your question each time, generally speaking the more information you add the more attention your question gets, getting you more question votes. The key is to keep updating your question with the new information you've found.

Comment: @JorgeCastro : Do bump mean going up in the question stack ?

Comment: It'll show up in the front page, which will give it attention, which will hopefully get your question more votes, which will then move it up the question stack.