# How to ask a following question?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, asking-questions

I've found a question corresponding to mine ([What is the purpose of favoriting questions?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2462/what-is-the-purpose-of-favoriting-questions)), but need some precisions ([Do favoriting questions help to get an answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6060/do-favoriting-questions-help-to-get-an-answer/)).

1. If [I had enough reputation](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/362/how-do-i-comment-on-a-post) : by adding in the question a comment? an answer written like a question? Something else ?
2. If I don't have enough reputation to comment or edit out of my questions : how ? Then, how do I link to the parent question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you're really asking a different question.

"What is X for?" exists.

Your question is, "Does X achieve A?"

If that's not answered in the more general question, then you usually have a separate question, and it's fine to post it separately. You can link to the related question if you judge it would be helpful.